# Altair chart with alpha-vantage pandas data

Tags: python, pandas, altair, alpha-vantage

I am struggling with plotting my pandas alpha vantage data with altair because i cant get the data to the way i want.

This is how it comes from my alpha-vantage query:

[image: alphavantagedata]

And this is how my code is now:

```
context = locals()
source = data[0]['1a. open (USD)']
print(source[0])

context["chart"] = alt.Chart(source).mark_area(
    line={'color': 'black'},
    color=alt.Gradient(
        gradient='linear',
        stops=[alt.GradientStop(color='white', offset=0),
               alt.GradientStop(color='black', offset=1)],
        x1=1,
        x2=1,
        y1=1,
        y2=0
    )
).encode(
    alt.X('date:T'),
    alt.Y('price:Q')
).interactive()
```

I get this error when i run the code:

```
altair.utils.schemapi.SchemaValidationError: Invalid specification

    altair.vegalite.v4.api.Chart->0, validating 'additionalProperties'

    Additional properties are not allowed (Timestamp('2018-05-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-07-18 
    00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-11-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-10-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018- 
    07-05 00:00
    ----- lots more here -----
    Timestamp('2020-05-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-05-08 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-10-05 
    00:00:00') were unexpected)
```

So the question is there how to get my pandas data as two arrays, one for the timestamps and one for the closing data value! So i can do like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                 'y': [5, 3, 6, 7, 2]})
alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`source` must be a pandas DataFrame; it appears that you are passing a tuple of timestamps. Pass a dataframe instead, and you will not see this error.

Because you have not included a full example of how the `data` variable was generated, I'm unable to offer more specific advice.

Comment: cc = CryptoCurrencies(key='ALPA_KEY', output_format='pandas') \n   data = cc.get_digital_currency_daily(symbol='BTC', market='USD') #This is the rest of the data-code!

Comment: It sounds like `data` is a pandas dataframe then... you should use that directly.